# How to convert string to list in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp

```
Just like
```

The String is

```
> "((1 0)(0 1))" 
required  
>((1 0)(0 1))
```

I am also using **intern** function but it returns in form of ((1\ 0)(0\ 1))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `read-from-string`:

```
(read-from-string "((1 0)(0 1))")
```

This function has many parameters and returns two values: the first is what you need, the list:

```
 CL-USER> (car (read-from-string "((1 0)(0 1))"))
 (1 0)
```

You can read about this function in the [official documentation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_fro.htm#read-from-string).